# Error fitting xgboost classification models with single predictor

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am trying to fit xgboost classification models with a single numeric predictor. There seems to be a bug that does not allow a feature matrix to be built when there is just one predictor variable.

I get the following error:

Error in xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(x[-trn_index, ], label = y[-trn_index], : xgb.DMatrix does not support construction from double

Here is my reprex showing the error:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(xgboost)
```

> Attaching package: 'xgboost'
> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
>
> ```
> slice
> ```

```
d <- tidyr::tibble(x1 = stats::runif(100, min = 0, max = 10),
                   x2 = stats::runif(100, min = 0, max = 10),
                   y = sample(c("yes", "no"), size = 100, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(y = factor(y))

head(d)
```

> ## A tibble: 6 × 3
>
> ```
>  x1    x2 y
> ```
>
> 1  8.78 4.97  no
> 2  1.86 4.32  yes
> 3  3.09 2.81  no
> 4  5.59 4.34  yes
> 5  4.42 7.56  no
> 6  2.62 0.761 yes

```
# fit model using both predictor variables

model_both <- boost_tree(learn_rate = 0.1,
                         tree_depth = 2,
                         mtry = 2,
                         trees = 100,
                         stop_iter = 20) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost",
             validation = 0.2) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  fit(y ~ ., data = d)

summary(model_both)
```

> ```
>     Length Class       Mode
> ```
>
> lvl      2     -none-      character
> spec     8     boost_tree  list
> fit     13     xgb.Booster list
> preproc  4     -none-      list
> elapsed  1     -none-      list

```
# fit model using only 1 predictor variable

model_x1 <- boost_tree(learn_rate = 0.1,
                       tree_depth = 2,
                       mtry = 2,
                       trees = 100,
                       stop_iter = 20) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost",
             validation = 0.2) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  fit(y ~ x1, data = d)
```

> Error in xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(x[-trn_index, ], label = y[-trn_index], : xgb.DMatrix does not support construction from double

Created on 2023-07-27 with reprex v2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in {parsnip}. Thanks for finding it!

I have created a PR in {parsnip} here https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/pull/994, that should fix the bug. You can install that version with `pak::pak("tidymodels/parsnip#994")`.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(xgboost)

d <- tidyr::tibble(x1 = stats::runif(100, min = 0, max = 10),
                   x2 = stats::runif(100, min = 0, max = 10),
                   y = sample(c("yes", "no"), size = 100, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(y = factor(y))

boost_tree(learn_rate = 0.1,
           tree_depth = 2,
           mtry = 2,
           trees = 100,
           stop_iter = 20) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost",
             validation = 0.2) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  fit(y ~ x1, data = d)
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> ##### xgb.Booster
#> raw: 22.4 Kb 
#> call:
#>   xgboost::xgb.train(params = list(eta = 0.1, max_depth = 2, gamma = 0, 
#>     colsample_bytree = 1, colsample_bynode = 1, min_child_weight = 1, 
#>     subsample = 1), data = x$data, nrounds = 100, watchlist = x$watchlist, 
#>     verbose = 0, early_stopping_rounds = 20, nthread = 1, objective = "binary:logistic")
#> params (as set within xgb.train):
#>   eta = "0.1", max_depth = "2", gamma = "0", colsample_bytree = "1", colsample_bynode = "1", min_child_weight = "1", subsample = "1", nthread = "1", objective = "binary:logistic", validate_parameters = "TRUE"
#> xgb.attributes:
#>   best_iteration, best_msg, best_ntreelimit, best_score, niter
#> callbacks:
#>   cb.evaluation.log()
#>   cb.early.stop(stopping_rounds = early_stopping_rounds, maximize = maximize, 
#>     verbose = verbose)
#> # of features: 1 
#> niter: 21
#> best_iteration : 1 
#> best_ntreelimit : 1 
#> best_score : 0.7004074 
#> best_msg : [1]   validation-logloss:0.700407 
#> nfeatures : 1 
#> evaluation_log:
#>     iter validation_logloss
#>        1          0.7004074
#>        2          0.7080396
#> ---                        
#>       20          0.8020192
#>       21          0.8032207
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>